# Measure wrapped string

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, word-wrap

I'm trying to create a Control that basically allows me to draw different strings underneath one another.
However, the strings' width may not be larger than the control's.
In order to solve that problem, I was thinking of passing a RectangleF object to the Graphics.DrawString method. That would wrap strings which are wider than the passed rectangle's width. Although this does solve the problem of not being able to see the whole string if it's too big, there is another problem. If I were to try something like this

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics; // Paint event
g.DrawString(someText, someFont, someBrush, new PointF(0, 0), someRectangleF);
g.DrawString(someMoreText, someFont, someBrush, new PointF(0, 12), someRectangleF);
```

the problem would be that if someText gets wrapped, the third line will paint text over of the first text, thus making it hard/impossible to be read.

I was looking for a solution for this problem, and I found some interesting links, which however included the use of a for loop which would measure each character's width and so on.
Is there any simpler ways of doing this?

Comment: Did you consider just using a TextBlock with Wrapping?  The control you are trying to build seems a lot like ListView.  Why a custom control?

Comment: I did consider using a ListView. However, my control represents a timetable which my program will be able to print. And printed ListViews don't really look good, so I've been trying to create my own control. Oh, and sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using WinForms. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you can use the [Graphics.MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bt8ty58.aspx) method to get the dimensions of the string and draw the next string accordingly?

```
SizeF size = g.MeasureString(someText, someFont, someRectangleF.Size.Width);
g.DrawString(someText, someFont, someBrush, new PointF(0, 0), someRectangleF);
g.DrawString(someMoreText, someFont, someBrush, new PointF(0, size.Height), someRectangleF);
```

Comment: Sadly no, I've tried that. MeasureString does not support word-wrap.

Comment: It does, to quote the documentation "The width parameter specifies the maximum value of the width component of the returned SizeF structure (Width). If the width parameter is less than the actual width of the string, the returned Width component is truncated to a value representing the maximum number of characters that will fit within the specified width. To accommodate the entire string, the returned Height component is adjusted to a value that allows displaying the string with character wrap." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bt8ty58.aspx

Comment: Oh, I see. I've actually read that page, I must have misunderstood it. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if the API changed over the past 5 years, but I was able to get that to work with:

drawing2.DrawString(text, font, textBrush, new RectangleF(0, yTextPlacement, textSize.Width, textSize.Height));