# How to highlight wrapped text in a control using the graphics?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+, highlight

I need to highlight the particular character in a control using the fill rect.
I can get the location of the text when it's not wrapped by using the `Graphics.MeasureString()` method like below,

```
var size = g.MeasureString(tempSearchText, style.Font, 0, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
```

[image]

If the text is wrapped then I'm not able to find the exact bounds of the character to highlight the text.

[image]

I need to get the exact bounds of the given character in the text which is wrapped. Provide your suggestion to achieve this scenario.

Comment: Can't you manually wrap the text using this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120555/measure-wrapped-string and then use your current methodology on the single line?

Comment: Is there any other way to get the location of the charater in the wrapped text?

Comment: You can use a `RichTextBox`, make the text non-selectable and make the control read-only. Then you can set `SelectionBackColor`  for highlighting some part of the text simply.

Comment: A lot depends on which controls you are using. For Textboxes and RichTextboxes you can get the char position with `PointF _P = [TheControlName].GetPositionFromCharIndex(TheCharIndex);` That char index may be returned by `[TheControlName].Text.IndexOf(_The‌​Char)` or any other search pattern you use to identify it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no clear specification of which controls to target, so I'm testing 3 different:
`TextBox`, `RichTextbox` and `ListBox`.

TextBox and RichTextbox have the same behavior and share the same tools, so there's no need to define two different methods to achieve the same result.
Of course RichTextbox offers many more options, including [RTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format).

Also, I'm testing both [`Graphics.DrawString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`TextRenderer.DrawText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext(v=vs.110).aspx).

This is the result of this test, so it's more clear what the code does.

[image]

**Warning**:
**For this example I'm using `Control.CreateGraphics()`, because `TextBox` and `RichTextBox` controls don't provide a `Paint()` event. For a real world application, you should create a Custom Control derived from `TextBox` or `RichTextBox`, override `WndPrc` and handle `WM_PAINT`**.

**1)** Highlight all **t** in a multiline TextBox control.

TextRenderer->DrawText():

```
//Define some useful flags for TextRenderer
TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.Top | 
                        TextFormatFlags.NoPadding | TextFormatFlags.WordBreak | 
                        TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl;
//The char to look for
char TheChar = 't';

//Find all 't' chars indexes in the text
List<int> TheIndexList = textBox1.Text.Select((chr, idx) => chr == TheChar ? idx : -1)
                                      .Where(idx => idx != -1).ToList();

//Or with Regex - same thing, pick the one you prefer
List<int> TheIndexList = Regex.Matches(textBox1.Text, TheChar.ToString())
                              .Cast<Match>()
                              .Select(chr => chr.Index).ToList();

//Using .GetPositionFromCharIndex(), define the Point [p] where the highlighted text is drawn
if (TheIndexList.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (int Position in TheIndexList)
    {
        Point p = textBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(Position);
        using (Graphics g = textBox1.CreateGraphics())
               TextRenderer.DrawText(g, TheChar.ToString(), textBox1.Font, p,
                                     textBox1.ForeColor, Color.LightGreen, flags);
    }
}
```

The same operation using `Graphics.FillRectangle()` and `Graphics.DrawString()`:

```
if (TheIndexList.Count > 0)
{
    using (Graphics g = textBox1.CreateGraphics())
    {
        foreach (int Position in TheIndexList)
        {
            PointF pF = textBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(Position);
            SizeF sF = g.MeasureString(TheChar.ToString(), textBox1.Font, 0,
                                       StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGreen, new RectangleF(pF, sF));
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(textBox1.ForeColor))
            {
                g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
                g.DrawString(TheChar.ToString(), textBox1.Font, brush, pF, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> There is no notable difference in behavior: `TextRenderer.DrawText()`
> and `Graphics.DrawString()` do the exact same thing here.
> Setting [`Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setcompatibletextrenderingdefault(v=vs.110).aspx) to `true` or
> `false` does not seem to have any affect (in the current context, at least).

**2)** Highlight some string patterns ("Words") in a TextBox control and a multiline RichTextbox control.

Using `TextRenderer` only, since there's no difference in behavior.

> I'm simply letting `IndexOf()` find the the first occurrence of the
> strings, but the same search pattern used before can take it's place. Regex works better.

```
string[] TheStrings = {"for", "s"};
foreach (string pattern in TheStrings)
{
    Point p = TextBox2.GetPositionFromCharIndex(TextBox2.Text.IndexOf(pattern));
    using (var g = TextBox2.CreateGraphics()) { 
        TextRenderer.DrawText(g, pattern, TextBox2.Font, p, 
                              TextBox2.ForeColor, Color.LightSkyBlue, flags);
    }
}

TheStrings = new string []{"m", "more"};
foreach (string pattern in TheStrings)
{
    Point p = richTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(pattern));
    using (Graphics g = richTextBox1.CreateGraphics())
        TextRenderer.DrawText(g, pattern, richTextBox1.Font, p,
                              richTextBox1.ForeColor, Color.LightSteelBlue, flags);
}
```

**3)** Highlight all **s** in all the `ListItems` of a ListBox control (of course it can be any other string :)

The `ListBox.DrawMode` is set to `Normal` and changed "on the fly" to `OwnerDrawVariable` to evaluate whether `TextRenderer` and `Graphics` behave differently here.

> There is a small difference: a different offset, relative to the left
> margin of the ListBox, compared to the standard implementation.
> TextRenderer, with `TextFormatFlags.NoPadding` renders 2 pixels to the
> left (the opposite without the flag). Graphics renders 1 pixel to the
> right.
>  Of course if `OwnerDrawVariable` is set in design mode,
> this will not be noticed.

```
string HighLightString = "s";
int GraphicsPaddingOffset = 1;
int TextRendererPaddingOffset = 2;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
}
```

> **How the following code works:**
>
> 1. Get all the positions in the `ListItem` text where the pattern (`string HighLightString`) appears.
> 2. Define an array of [`CharacterRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.characterrange(v=vs.110).aspx) structures with the position and length of the pattern.
> 3. Fill a [`StringFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformat(v=vs.110).aspx) with all the `CharacterRange` structs using [`.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformat.setmeasurablecharacterranges(v=vs.110).aspx)
> 4. Define an array of Regions using [`Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535796(v=vs.85).aspx) passing the initialized `StringFormat`.
> 5. Define an array of Rectangles sized using [`Region.GetBounds()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.region.getbounds(v=vs.110).aspx)
> 6. Fill all the Rectangles with the highlight color using [`Graphics.FillRectangles()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fillrectangles(v=vs.110).aspx)
> 7. Draw the `ListItem` text.

`TextRenderer.DrawText()` implementation:

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();

    TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.Top | TextFormatFlags.NoPadding |
                            TextFormatFlags.WordBreak | TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl;
    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X + TextRendererPaddingOffset, 
                                     e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height);

    string ItemString = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.Items[e.Index]);
    List<int> TheIndexList = Regex.Matches(ItemString, HighLightString)
                                  .Cast<Match>()
                                  .Select(s => s.Index).ToList();

    if (TheIndexList.Count > 0)
    {
        CharacterRange[] CharRanges = new CharacterRange[TheIndexList.Count];
        for (int CharX = 0; CharX < TheIndexList.Count; CharX++)
            CharRanges[CharX] = new CharacterRange(TheIndexList[CharX], HighLightString.Length);

        StringFormat format = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        format.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(CharRanges);

        Region[] regions = e.Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges(ItemString, e.Font, e.Bounds, format);

        RectangleF[] rectsF = new RectangleF[regions.Length];
        for (int RFx = 0; RFx < regions.Length; RFx++)
            rectsF[RFx] = regions[RFx].GetBounds(e.Graphics);

        e.Graphics.FillRectangles(Brushes.LightGreen, rectsF);
    }
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, ItemString, e.Font, bounds, e.ForeColor, flags);
}
```

`Graphics.DrawString()` implementation

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X - GraphicsPaddingOffset,
                                     e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height);

    string ItemString = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.Items[e.Index]);
    List<int> TheIndexList = Regex.Matches(ItemString, HighLightString)
                                  .Cast<Match>()
                                  .Select(s => s.Index).ToList();

    StringFormat format = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericDefault);
    if (TheIndexList.Count > 0)
    {
        CharacterRange[] CharRanges = new CharacterRange[TheIndexList.Count];
        for (int CharX = 0; CharX < TheIndexList.Count; CharX++)
            CharRanges[CharX] = new CharacterRange(TheIndexList[CharX], HighLightString.Length);

        format.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(CharRanges);
        Region[] regions = e.Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges(ItemString, e.Font, e.Bounds, format);

        RectangleF[] rectsF = new RectangleF[regions.Length];
        for (int RFx = 0; RFx < regions.Length; RFx++)
            rectsF[RFx] = regions[RFx].GetBounds(e.Graphics);

        e.Graphics.FillRectangles(Brushes.LightGreen, rectsF);
    }
    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor))
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ItemString, e.Font, brush, bounds, format);
}
```

> Note:
>  Depending on the `ListBox.DrawMode`, it may become necessary to
> subscribe the `ListBox.MeasureItem()` event or set the `.ItemHeight`
> property to the corrent value.

```
private void listBox1_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
      e.ItemHeight = listBox1.Font.Height;
}
```

Comment: I was needing to read this one [two days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60983817/how-to-highlight-search-arabic-text-in-datagridview/61005624#61005624) ago.