# how to change the color of certain words in C#

Tags: c#, text, colors, windows-10, richtextbox

How do I change the color of a certain word as I type, like lets say I type "print" I want it to change it from the default black to lets say blue without interrupting typing or changing anything else, how would I do that?

Comment: What API? ASP.NET? WinForm? WPF? UWP?

Comment: I'm Not sure I'm just making a Desktop Application

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [How to color different words with different colors in a RichTextBox while a user is writing and raise an event when that colored text is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48358496/7444103) (reading the title takes more time than implementing it).

Comment: You might be also interested in [How to highlight wrapped text in a control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48257170/7444103) (series of tests).